# Convert my SQL Server Stored Procedure to PostgressSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

I have MSSQL procedure which contains SQL select statement now I want to covert MSSQL stored procedure to PostgreSQL any help will be appreciated.

Below is SQL stored Procedure this I want to convert into PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Common_SP]
@Type int=NULL
AS
BEGIN
IF(@Type =1)
BEGIN
    select * from abc where configuration_id in (100009,
    100010) or device_id=100000
END
ELSE IF(@Type = 2)
BEGIN
    select * from PQR
    select * from XYZ
END
ELSE IF(@Type = 3)
BEGIN
    select t.TempId as Id, t.TemplateName,t.TemplateDesc,s.AssetId,s.Value as AssetValue,t.CreatedBy 
      ,t.DeviceType,
      i.InjestionType,g.GatewayType from Template t
    inner join PQR i on t.InjestionType = i.Id
    inner join XYZ s on t.TempId=s.TemplateId
    inner join MNO g on t.DeviceType=g.Id
--select * from 
END
ELSE IF(@Type = 4)
BEGIN
    select TempId,TemplateName from Template
END
END
```

Comment: Please explain what it does for those that don't know T-SQL

Comment: As far as I can tell, this returns different result sets based on the passed type. This is not really possible (or easily possible) in Postgres. And procedures aren't used to return results either in Postgres, for that you would use a set returning function. The best thing to do is to put each select into a separate function and change the _calling_ code to call different functions.

Comment: perhaps you can achieve in PG using "record" as return datatype  from functions, of course, you need to know what is returning your function to understand the result